# How would I map a complex json file with nested objects to java objects?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a complex **Json** file made up of several nested objects and array of objects. The first object is an "OptionChain" that has an object called "Result". "Result" has nested objects: "Quote" and "Options". Finally, "Options" has nested array of objects named "Call" and "Put".

I have all the class variables annotated with `@JSonProperty` and using **Spring Boot** with **Jackson** to deal with the Object Mapping. I am new with using **Jackson** and Object Mapping.

When I run the program, I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "optionChain" (class com.thompson.OptionsImpliedMovement.data.OptionChain), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "result"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"optionChain":{"result":[{"underlyingSymbol":"KO","expirationDates":[1550188800,1550793600,1551398400,1552003200,1552608000,1553212800,1553817600,1555545600,1558051200,1561075200,1565913600,1579219200,1610668800],"strikes":[37.0,38.0,40.5,41.5,42.5,43.5,44.5,45.5,46.5,47.5,48.5,49.5,50.5,51.0,51.5,52.0,53.0,53.5,54.0],"hasMiniOptions":false,"quote":{"language":"en-US","region":"US","quoteType":"EQUITY","quoteSourceName":"Nasdaq Real Time Price","currency":"USD","exchangeDataDelayedBy":0,"earnin"[truncated 10817 chars]; line: 1, column: 17] (through reference chain: com.thompson.OptionsImpliedMovement.data.OptionChain["optionChain"])
```

Here is the main class, pom.xml, and two of my java classes:

Main:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.thompson.OptionsImpliedMovement.data.OptionChain;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Collections;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OptionsImpliedMovementApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OptionsImpliedMovementApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        String resourceURL = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/ko";
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(resourceURL, HttpMethod.GET,entity, String.class);

        String rawJson = response.getBody();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        OptionChain optionChain = objectMapper.readValue(rawJson, OptionChain.class);

    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.thompson</groupId>
    <artifactId>OptionsImpliedMovement</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>OptionsImpliedMovement</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

OptionChain:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class OptionChain {
    @JsonProperty("result")
    public Result result;

}
```

Result:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty; 

public class Result  {

    @JsonProperty("underlyingSymbol")
    public String symbol;
    @JsonProperty("expirationDates")
    public long[] expirationDates;
    @JsonProperty("strikes")
    public double[] strikes;
    @JsonProperty("hasMiniOptions")
    public boolean hasMiniOptions;
    @JsonProperty("quote")
    public Quote quote;
    @JsonProperty("options")
    public Options option;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of hierarchy of **Json** file:
[Hierarchy of Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsgYW.png)

And finally here is the full **Json** file attached:
[Full Json File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UU7g4yAottQ9jioj50uVzR7n_lMyhoq9/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you're unmarshaling JSON that is `{ "optionChain": {...} }` but you're doing so directly into an `OptionChain`. Instead, you need to define a class that has a single `OptionChain` member, because you are unmarshaling the outer object that contains this `optionChain` field (The `{ }` that surrounds the entire response is the object you're trying to unmarshal).

So, for example:

```
public class OptionChainResponse {

   @JsonProperty("optionChain")
   private OptionChain optionChain;

   // getter/setter
}
```

And then:

```
OptionChainResponse optionChainResponse = objectMapper.readValue(rawJson, OptionChainResponse.class);
// do some validation or checking maybe
OptionChain optionChain = optionChainResponse.getOptionChain();
```